# Generating textual images using QImage (qt)

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I am trying to create images from text using QImage.

As per the documentation here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum

We cannot use `QImage::Format_Indexed8` with QImage.
I cannot use `QImage::Format_Mono` or `QImage::Format_MonoLSB` due to its low quality.

My question is:

- What is the best way to create textual image (batch processing) so
  that we can get decent quality with minimum file size?
- Is there is any way to do image compression through QT once the image is created to reduce the file size?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sample code that does it:

```
QImage image(100, 50, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.fillRect(image.rect(), Qt::yellow);
painter.drawText(image.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, "hello, world");
image.save("output.png");
```

It creates this image:

[image]

The output format is PNG, so it will have good compression without losing any quality.

Answer (score 1):

There's this example, which shows you how to use `QPainter::drawText` and work with fonts:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/painting-fontsampler.html

`QImage::save` has support for a variety of formats and quality levels:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Although `QImage` is in QtCore, `QPainter` and the text drawing routines are in QtGUI.  So on a Linux system this will require an X server to be running:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1758-QPainter-in-console-apps

Comment: QtGui does not need X server. It depends on how it was built. If built for Qt/X11 yes, but not for Qt/E.